# Message: user order resource type [classic] not exists in [random] when trying to RunInstances on command line

Tags: alibaba-cloud

When trying to create an ECS instance via cli tools I get the error in subject and I can't find what it means. For example:

```
$ ./aliyun ecs RunInstances --Amount 1 --ImageId m-0xidtg6bbw1s8voux52d --InstanceType ecs.n1.medium  --InstanceName Composer-Test-VM-1 --SecurityGroupId sg-0xi4w9isg0p1ytj1qbhf
ERROR: SDK.ServerError
ErrorCode: InvalidResourceType.NotSupported
Recommend: 
RequestId: 1B3E65BD-D181-4552-9A58-599FC51924A7
Message: user order resource type [classic] not exists in [random]
```

I have credentials configured in `~/.aliyun/config.json`.

The default region in config is `us-east-1`, the ImageId and SecurityGroupId are both in the same region.

I tried a few other instance types and either I get the same error message or [classic] is replaced by the prefix of the instance type. This leads me to think I can't create virtual machines from some of these instance types in my region but I have no idea why.

Does anyone know what is causing this specific error or where to find more documentation about it ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the culprit here. Although not stated (e.g. in `--help`) the `--VSwitchId` option is mandatory when specifying a `--SecurityGroupId`. The VSwitch needs to be in the same availability zone as your security group.

Answer (score 0):

On [this link](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25499.htm), check out the following documentation under "Description":

For network configuration:

- To create an instance in a VPC, you must specify a VPC and a VSwitch. One instance can belong only to one VSwitch.
- When you specify **VSwitchId**, ensure that the security group and VSwitch specified by **SecurityGroupId** and **VSwitchId** belong to the same VPC.
- If you specify both **VSwitchId** and **PrivateIpAddress**, ensure that the private IP address specified by **PrivateIpAddress** is within the CIDR block of the VSwitch.
- **PrivateIpAddress** is dependent on **VSwitchId**. You cannot only specify the **PrivateIpAddress** parameter.

**Also Note:** The Alibaba Cloud product APIs are divided into RPC API and RESTful API. Most products use RPC style. When you use Alibaba Cloud CLI to call the interface, APIs of different styles have different calling methods.

Check out the following link: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/110344.htm

Hope this helps!